# Connecting to a MySQL Database (on my own Webspace) via AndroidStudio

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, gradle, connector

I'm using Android Studio for 2 Weeks now and I want to write a code, in order to connect to a MySQL Database which is on my own Domain Webspace.

I've tried the Java DB Connector from MySQL itself (mysql-connector-java-gpl-5.1.34.msi).

So first of all i tried the JDBC Connector but i figured out this one is only for SQLLite Databases.

I have bound in the Mysql Java Connector from MYSQL.com and edited the build.gradle and the settings.gradle

**SETTINGS GRADLE**

```
include ':app'
include ':Libraries/Mysql-Connector-Java-3.0.17-ga'
include ':Mysql-Connector-Java-3.0.17-ga'
```

and the latest version of the connector (mysql-connector-java-gpl-5.1.34.msi)
into ROOT-libs(selfmade directory) as my DirectoryName was MySQLJ.

I am using API 19

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "##################" (my company name censored)
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':libraries:mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga')
}
```

**I TRIED IT WITH minifyEnable true and false**

so everytime I want to rebuild the Project as taught in this Tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk

i get this error exception

1. *Error:(26, 0) Project with path ':libraries:mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga' could not be found in project ':app'.*
2. *Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.*

so I searched on stackoverflow for answers and i came to this result:

(problem with ~ default) this library is not for AndroidStudio? Because this library hasn't got a own build.gradle so the source of the error exception with this default thingy is the uncompatible library?

**Is it possible to write a code to connect to a MYSQL Database with Android Studio? and Where can i find a library for the MYSQL Connector????**

Comment: I have the exact same poblem...

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

Download and paste the mysql-connector into your libs folder. WARNING: the latest version (mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar) throws some problems while compiling (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191856/android-jdbc-mysql-java-connector-apppredexdebug/33874206#33874206)). I recommend an older version (mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar) from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=13460).

In your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    //other stuff
    compile files('libs/mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar')
}
```

To get the connection use:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
String connection = "jdbc:mysql://"+ your_ip + ":"+ your_port +"/"+   database_name;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, user, pass);
```

PD: This only works if you use the connection from and AsyncTask