# android JDBC mysql java connector app:preDexDebug

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to learn how to use the JDBC to connect a application to a MySQL database.

I'm using the Android Studio.

I downloaded "mysql-connector-java-5.1.37" from the MySQL website.

Just for put the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar" in libs folder of a Hello World application and compile I receive :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.myaplication.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: how do you build your project? Using gradle build? You should try gradle clean build!

Comment: i just press the run button of android studio. how do i do that? (sorry, im new at this )

Comment: Please don't do this for real projects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android

Comment: @MorrisonChang thx for the help, but im having problem using webservice too hahahhaa..

Comment: I have EXACTLY the same problem. Did anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to sync your project
`Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

And then rebuild your project:
`build -> rebuild project`

Comment: You get the error you posted while building the project? Can you please post your complete gradle log when building

Comment: yes, while building.. dont fit here, but starts bug here:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was in the mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar file. I downloaded an older version (mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar) from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=13460) and worked like a charm.

To get the connection use:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
String connection = "jdbc:mysql://"+ your_ip + ":"+ your_port +"/"+ database_name;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, user, pass);
```

Just in case, don't forget to compile it in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    //other stuff
    compile files('libs/mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar')
}
```

PD: This only works if you use the connection from and AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Because Distributed mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar is compiled for Java1.8, current Android dex compiler cannot recognize it.

```
$ javap -v com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC42Helper.class| grep "major version"
  major version: 52
```

On the oher hand, mysql-connector-java-5.1.**36**.jar is compiled for Java1.6.

```
$ javap -v com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC4Connection.class |grep "major version"
  major version: 50
```

[5.1.37 supports JDBC4.2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/en/news-5-1-37.html), so requires Java1.8.