# Android MySQL connector (JDBC) error after importing library

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I'm writing an app that needs to connect to a MySQL Database trought a class that use JDBC libraries.

I copied the mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar file in libs folder, then I import it from "project structure" in Android Studio.

Now in the gradle.build file for the Module i'm using (app) i have

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar')
}
```

But when I try to launch the app I get this error

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

If I delete/comment that line, the launch goes fine. What can I do? Thank you

Comment: duplicate. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34264548/4506703

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect mysql with the file mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar 
in android

This tutorial hope can help you
[Android MySQL Client](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-mysql-client.html)